# how to create a dropping list from (1 to 9) so the user can choose how many tickets to book?

Tags: python, django

so im working on a online booking project for trains and my project works fine but only the user can book 1 ticketeach time and i want to make him being able to book more than 1 ticket,base on that choice also create the amount of forms as tickets and im new with django and i dont know where to start looking for a solution for this :(

## Views.py

```
imports...
# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create your views here.
def details_page(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        end_station_id = request.GET.get('station')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        end_station_id = request.POST.get('to_station')
    # print(request.GET.get('to_station'))
    # Ticket.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
    trips = Trip.objects.filter(end_station_id=end_station_id)
    context = {'trips': trips}
    return render(request, 'details/details.html', context)


def trips_page(request, trip_id):
    trip = get_object_or_404(Trip, pk=trip_id)
    error = None
    ticket = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        ticket = Ticket(trip=trip, first_name=first_name, middle_name=middle_name,
                        last_name=last_name, email=email, gender=gender)
        try:
            ticket.full_clean()
            ticket.save()
            return redirect('tickets', ticket_id=ticket.id)
        except ValidationError as e:
            error = dict(e)
            print(e)
    context = {'trip': trip, 'error': error, 'ticket': ticket}
    return render(request, 'details/trips.html', context)
```

## Models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
    )

    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, related_name="tickets", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booking_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_string], null=True, max_length=100, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_string], null=True, max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_string], null=True, max_length=100, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.first_name)
```

Comment: https://github.com/pokipoki2010/Safrat.git

Comment: Is your challange the dropdown with number of forms or to actually generate that many forms? generating a dropdown is pretty straight simple. use a model.Textinput with choices 1-6. If you are stuck with the generation of multiple forms, formset in django will be your solution.

Comment: @Neel yes its part of the challenge, if you dont mind an example would be much better. thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go on about doing this would be to allow the user to select the number of tickets he wants to purchase and to create these either one by one (as my example) or by using [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). One by one allows you to retrieve each of the IDs.

```
def trips_page(request, trip_id):
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
        ticket_count = request.POST.get('ticket_count', 1)
        tickets_ids = []

        for i in range(ticket_count):
            # create ticket here
            # append tickets ids

        if error is None:
            return redirect('tickets', tickets_ids=tickets_ids)

    context = {'trip': trip, 'error': error, 'ticket': ticket}
    return render(request, 'details/trips.html', context)
```

A problem with this solution is that either you enter all of the users' personal information for the each ticket (first name, last name etc), or you allow the user to enter that information afterwards.

One way to do this would be to have an `Order` model to which tickets are linked.
Once the purchase is made for example, you can enter the information for each ticket in a subsequent page/form.

Comment: awesome i got the idea on how should it be in the views.py but im also struggling at the html template too( how to represent the list with the tickets number)